# Imposing negative spacing between columns in alignat environment

Tags: spacing, alignat

I have the following code (don't mind about the lyrics: they are included just for comparison between text and math mode):

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{bm}
  \begin{document}
  I think about closing the door/And lately I think of it more/I'm living well out of my time/I feel like I'm losing my mind$\ |\ $I should be at the table round/A servant of the crown/The keeper of the sign/To sparkle and to shine

  \newlength{\supal}
  \settowidth{\supal}{$h_{(p+1,r,s-1)}$,}
  \begin{alignat*}{2}
  \uparrow=&
  \begin{cases}
  h_{(2,1,n-1)},&\ \text{if}\ n>2\,;\\
  \makebox[\supal][l]{$\bm2$,}&\ \text{if}\ n=2\,.
  \end{cases} &\downarrow=&
  \begin{cases}
  h_{(1,2,n)},&\ \text{if}\ n>2\,;\\
  \makebox[\supal][l]{$\bm1$,}&\ \text{if}\ n=2\,.
  \end{cases}\\[3mm]
  \uparrow\hspace{-1mm}\mbox{\tiny$\circ$}\,\bm j=&\,\pmb\uparrow\!\bm j\ ; & \downarrow\hspace{-1mm}\mbox{\tiny$\circ$}\,\bm j=&\,\pmb\downarrow\!\bm j\,.\\[3mm]
  \uparrow\hspace{-1mm}\mbox{\tiny$\circ$}\,h_{(p,r,s)}=&
  \begin{cases}
  h_{(p+1,r,s)},&\ \text{if}\ p+s-r<n\,;\\
  h_{(p+1,r,s-1)},&\ \text{if}\ p+s-r=n\ \text{and}\ s-r>1\,;\\
  \bm n,&\ \text{otherwise}\,.
  \end{cases} & & \\[3mm]
  \downarrow\hspace{-1mm}\mbox{\tiny$\circ$}\,h_{(p,r,s)}=&
  \begin{cases}
  h_{(p-1,r,s)},&\ \text{if}\ p>1\,;\\
  h_{(1,r+1,s)},&\ \text{if}\ p=1\ \text{and}\ s-r>1\,;\\
  \makebox[\supal][l]{$\bm1$,}&\ \text{otherwise}\,.
  \end{cases} & &
  \end{alignat*}
  \end{document}
```

---

The output is

[image]

The first `cases` environment with 3 clauses (third line in the `alignat` environment) has excessive width, which forces the second column to be far too right, even out of the margins (as the auxiliary lyrics shows). This occurs even though `alignat` environment places no spacing between columns.

I would like to know if there is a way to impose negative spacing between columns in the `alignat` environment; of course, in typical cases this would cause the corresponding (adjacent) columns to overlap, but not in my example.

Comment: if i had just one or two "too long" lines in the left-hand column, i would choose a line of a length that i like, and wrap (the right-hand side) of all longer lines in `\mathrlap{...}`, which will make latex ignore their length.  requires `mathtools`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the content you want to reduce the width of inside a box of fixed width that suits your needs.

Below I've created a similar mock-up to your scenario and placed the long content - `a very long condition that is very long` - inside a zero-width box that is `l`eft-aligned. This allows the upper-right `cases` to now be left-aligned to `otherwise3`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  a &= \begin{cases}
    b, \text{if $c = d$} \\
    e, \text{otherwise1}
  \end{cases} &
  f &= \begin{cases}
    g, \text{if $h = i$} \\
    j, \text{otherwise2}
  \end{cases} \\
  k &= \begin{cases}
    l, \makebox[0pt][l]{a very long condition that is very long} \\
    m, \text{otherwise3}
  \end{cases}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Although this does not address the general problem (*genuine* negative space between columns), it is a very clever solution.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas: You'd have to place negative space for a number of instances. In my approach you address the problem area and everything else takes care of itself.